# Aligning images to the left with centered video

Tags: html, image, video, web

http://jsfiddle.net/Vlastenec/akod1L0n/

```
<div style="text-align: center;">

    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/OE6rrDEnm4c" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I'm new to HTML and did a lot of searching for a solution, but I can't seem to figure this out.

The gap that gets created on the left I want to be filled with the image in line with the centered video. Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is that you're combining fluid (variable) and fixed dimensional attributes (width/height). Try fixing your widths to a design window width, and that should help. Alternatively, scale everything fluidly (ie. the video too).

Comment: Where in the code exactly? In the images or the video?

Comment: Just fiddled with the widths and floats real quick: http://jsfiddle.net/akod1L0n/9/ you could try a table structure as well, which would be a lot more manageable.

Comment: I've gotten it to do that. I guess what I'm really looking for is the video fixed in the center with the images to the left of it. I'm still new, so dealing with fixed and variable dimensional attributes is still a bit advanced. I'll try a table structure. How would you ultimately approach this kind of styling?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_tables.asp

Comment: Worked great! Any idea why there's that inconsistent gap between the first and second image? http://jsfiddle.net/Vlastenec/akod1L0n/10/

Comment: Just had to include these in the video `<td>`element: `<td rowspan="2" valign="top">` and you get http://jsfiddle.net/akod1L0n/12/